# Given a 2D array of RGB pixels, how do you sort them into an HSV color-selector like order?

Tags: arrays, sorting, colors

Let us assume that we have an image containing a 2D grid of pixels, each pixel assigned a random RGB color value. (We can also consider it as an HSV color value if that is easier).

I wanted to sort those into [an image whose HSV values are sorted like in this image](https://linangdata.com/color-picker/). The output image will have the same pixel dimensions as the source image.

My approach was to iterate over each row of the input image and sort each pixel using their HSV saturation values. After this, I iterate over each column and then sort them by their HSV hue. This results in an image whose sorting is not yet optimal, and it results in jagged colors since pixels are not placed in the right location.

To fix this jaggedness, I have added some randomness into the source image so that each pixel is exchanged by a neighboring pixel randomly in the vertical direction. This improved the jaggedness somewhat, and resulted in pictures [like this](https://ibb.co/Nm046Jd), but does not actually solve the problem.

Which algorithm would best suit this purpose? Please note that I am not talking about sorting algorithms--of course, I will still use quick sort for this. However, I am not sure how to approach the sorting of a 1D array and then sorting it into a 2D array.

I would really appreciate some guidelines on how to approach this. Thanks for any suggestion!